# How to replace multiple values across different datasets in SPSS

Tags: spss

I currently have two datasets, RTWANEW2016.sav and MERGED.sav.

RTWANEW2016:

```
+----+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| id |    date    | value1 | value2 | value3 | value4 | value5 | value6 |
+----+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|  1 | 01-03-2006 |      3 |      9 |     85 |    766 |      3 |     45 |
|  1 | 03-23-2010 |     56 |     34 |     23 |     33 |    556 |     43 |
|  2 | 12-04-2014 |     56 |    655 |    523 |    566 |      9 |      9 |
|  3 | 07-23-2011 |     34 |     56 |    661 |     23 |     22 |     11 |
|  4 | 03-05-2007 |     45 |    345 |    222 |    556 |   4566 |      4 |
+----+------------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

MERGED:

```
+----+------------+--------+--------+--------+
| id |    date    | value4 | value5 | value6 |
+----+------------+--------+--------+--------+
|  1 | 01-03-2006 |    345 |     44 |   5345 |
|  2 | 12-04-2014 |    522 |     55 |   5444 |
|  4 | 03-05-2007 |    234 |     88 |   9001 |
+----+------------+--------+--------+--------+
```

I want to update RTWANEW2016 with the values from variables "value4", "value5" and "value6" from MERGED.

*Notice that some data RTWANEW2016 has duplicate ID's, but different dates, so I would need to sort by both id and date*

Answer (score 1):

See the [`UPDATE`](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLVMB_21.0.0/com.ibm.spss.statistics.help/syn_update_overview.htm) command which is designed to achieve this.

> Overview (UPDATE command)
>
> UPDATE replaces values in a master file with updated values recorded
>   in one or more files called transaction files. Cases in the master
>   file and transaction file are matched according to a key variable.
>
> The master file and the transaction files must be IBM® SPSS®
>   Statistics data files or datasets available in the current session,
>   including the active dataset. UPDATE replaces values and creates a new
>   active dataset, which replaces the original active dataset.
>
> UPDATE is designed to update values of existing variables for existing
>   cases. Use MATCH FILES to add new variables to a data file and ADD
>   FILES to add new cases.

```
UPDATE FILE='/RTWANEW2016.sav' 
  /FILE='/MERGED.sav' 
  /BY=ID Date.
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! But in MERGED, I have some variables that are not included in RTWANEW2016, and I only want to update a specific selection. Say for example, that MERGED contained "value7" and "value8" variables, but I only wanted to copy over the new data from "value4", "value5" and "value6". Can I still incorporate UPDATE in some way? @Jignesh

Comment: You would `DROP` the variables you didn't want updating. See command help for further details.